# How to create a function to fill the region to a certain width?

Tags: emacs

Sometimes I justify text in emacs using `C-u 70 M-x fill-region`.

I would like to have a function in my `.emacs` file that has a parameter so that I can use a shortcut to call the function instead of having to do `C-u 70 fill-region`. I would have 2 shortcuts, one uses the default 70 and another asks for a parameter.

I'm very new to emacs programming but I've been using emacs for a while now. If there is a solution for this, could you please explain how to do it?

Comment: You say that you want 2 shortcuts. Does that mean that you want key commands to be bound to the functions? If so, which key commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefix a function with `C-h f` you can read documentation for it. If you do it for `fill-region` it shows, among other things:

```
The `fill-column' variable controls the width.
```

And if you check [the Emacs manual on Fill commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fill-Commands.html) you can read:

> The maximum line width for filling is specified by the buffer-local
>   variable `fill-column`. The default value (see
>   [Locals](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Locals.html#Locals))
>   is 70. The easiest way to set `fill-column` in the current buffer is
>   to use the command `C-x f` (`set-fill-column`). With a numeric
>   argument, it uses that as the new fill column. With just `C-u` as
>   argument, it sets `fill-column` to the current horizontal position of
>   point.

This explains how `C-u 70 M-x fill-region` works. It also shows that the width to fill with can be set via `C-x f`. Thus, it may not be necessary to write a function that asks for a parameter, i.e. you could use `C-x f` and `fill-region` instead.

If you still want new functions to do this you can use the following:

```lisp
(defun fill-region-ask-width (fill-width)
  "Asks for a width and fills the region to it"
  (interactive "nFill region to column: ")
  (fill-region-width fill-width))

(defun fill-region-width-70 ()
  "Fills the region with width 70"
  (interactive)
  (fill-region-width 70))

(defun fill-region-width (fill-width)
  "Fills the region with the given width"
  (set-fill-column fill-width)
  (fill-region (region-beginning) (region-end)))
```

The functions are explained by their [doc strings](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/DocString) but here are some more notes:

- `fill-region-ask-width` takes one argument which it gets by asking the user and it treats that number as an integer (`n`)  and passes it to `fill-region-prompt-width`.
- `fill-region-width-70` merely has a hard-coded number that it passes to `fill-region-prompt-width`.
- `fill-region-width` is a helper function to modularize what the other two functions have in common. It is not defined as interactive so it is not possible to call via `M-x`. It sets `fill-column` to the given argument and fills the region`.

For learning how to write Emacs functions and binding them to keys see [Learn Elisp For Emacs: Lesson 4-2 - Adding Custom Functions To Emacs](http://learn-elisp-for-emacs.org/contents/lesson-4-2-adding-custom-functions-to-emacs.html).